# Read asp.net dynamic textbox content length using c#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am using the below code to create a dynamic textbox and their onchange event.Event fired successfully and it doesn't return any value.Please help me to solve this.

```
txt_box.Attributes.Add("onchange", "loadValues('" + txt_box.ClientID + "')");

 function loadValues(controlName) {
        alert(controlName);
        //control name comes here
        var txtValue = document.getElementById(controlName);
       //control also return null
        if (txtValue.value.length > 0)
        {
          alert(txtValue.value.length); 
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was just about to answer the same as Ankush Jain, but then none jquery version:

```
function loadValues(control) {
        alert(control.id);
        //control name comes here
        var txtValue = control.value;
        //control also return null
        if (txtValue.length > 0) {
            alert(txtValue.length);
        }
    }


txt_box.Attributes.Add("onchange", "loadValues(this);");
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following

```
txt_box.Attributes.Add("onchange", "loadValues(this)");


 function loadValues(controlName) {
    if($(controlName).attr('id').length > 0){
       var id=  $(controlName).attr('id');
       var val= $('#'+id).val();
       alert(val);
    }
 }
```